# Doubts about function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, syntax

I'm running this function in R that returns me a value of the site.

```
sergito<- function(empresa) {
  url <- paste(sprintf("http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/servidores/Servidor-ListaServidores.asp?bogus=1&Pagina=1&TextoPesquisa="),empresa, sep="")
  id <- readLines(url)
  pos <- grep('IdServidor',id)
  x <- id[ pos:(pos) ]
  x1 <- substr(x,64,70)
  return(x1)
}

nome <- c('sergio%20henrique%20almeida%20da%20silva%20junior',
          'sergio%20henrique%20almeida%20da%20silva%20filho',
          'sergio%20henrique%20almeida%20da%20silva%20junior')
empresa <- cbind(as.data.frame(nome))
empresa <- empresa[,1]
```

When a I run the syntax below my code stop because Sergio Henrique Almeida da Silva Filho don´t exist. How to continue running the code? Using loop?

```
resultado<-data.frame(empresa=NA,id=NA)
for(i in 1:length(empresa)) {
  resposta <- sergito(empresa[i])
  resultado[i,"empresa"] <- as.character(empresa[i])
  resultado[i,"id"]< - as.character(resposta[[1]])
}
resultado
```

Comment: Thanks Dear! I solve this using `resposta<-try(sergito(empresa[i]))`

Comment: Or, you can check ahead if url exists using `url.exists()` from the `RCurl` package

Comment: if you've solved your own problem, feel free to post your answer (you may have to wait a little while).  Now that you know that `try` is the answer, you may also be able to search StackOverflow for `[r] try` and find a duplicate.  If you link it the comments, someone with higher rep can close your question.

Comment: Where  Marat Talipov???

Comment: Dear Ben Bolker I believe that this code can be improved because the try is not the best solution.

Comment: @shasj I meant to insert additional check `if (!url.exists(url)) return()` between the lines `url <- ...` and `id <- ...`. In this way, you would avoid calling `readLines` on non-existing url, and `sergito` will return `NULL`.

Comment: You have lots of weird code here. You don't need `sprintf` *and* `paste`.  `pos:(pos)` is just `pos`.  The call to `cbind` does nothing.  In fact, you spend two lines defining `empresa` to be exactly the same thing as `nome`.  You have `< -` where you mean `<-`.  You use a `for` loop where you want `lapply`.  The call `as.character(resposta[i])` does nothing since it is already a character, and you should convert `empresa` to be a character vector before the loop. Pro-tip: Read your code before you post it somewhere public.